# Swift string interpolation at runtime

Tags: swift, string-interpolation

I'm looking to implement some simple string templating in Swift and am wondering what the built-in options are for replacing macros in a string with values **at runtime**.

It would be awesome if there were a way for me to use the string interpolation syntax `"\(variable)"` at runtime, but I'm guessing these are actually parsed at compile time since the macros can contain actual code.

I've also found a `String` constructor that accepts a format string in Objective-C style, using %@, etc.

```
let myString = String(format: "Hello %@", name)
```

That could work, though I like the syntax less. I'm just wondering if there are better approaches I should take, or if it would be better to just write my own.

Being able to execute commands (like operators or method/property calls) within the macro would be awesome, but not required (and considering how static a language Swift is, not expected).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're looking to do (could you possibly give an example of usage in pseudo-swifty-code?). Possibly you can make use of runtime introspection (`Mirror(reflecting: ...)`) and subclassing `NSObject` for access to `self.valueForKey(<String>)...` and `self.setValue(<value>, forKey: <String>))` to set up some(non-swifty)thing. But possibly I'm not understanding what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah this is probably what I will end up doing if I roll my own string replacement syntax. I was just wondering if there was any decent support for that built-in. An example would be something like `"Hello there, \(firstName)!"` and being able to resolve that at runtime (obviously with some set context), not compile time.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Foundation

let serverName = "Fantastic"
var resultString = "We are using $SERVERNAME$"

if let range = resultString.rangeOfString("$SERVERNAME$") {
  resultString.replaceRange(range, with: serverName)
}
```

You could, of course, implement a `String` extension if you are going to be using this regularly.

```
extension String {
    func replaceString(sourceString:String, withNewElements newElements:String) throws {
    //implementation left for the reader
        let userInfo = ["missingString": sourceString,
            "message": "Substring '\(sourceString)' not found in '\(self)'"]
        throw NSError(domain: "ReplaceStringFailure", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```